# Nome do usuário com ficheiro Excel aberto - VBA

Tags: vba, servidor

**Objetivamente**:
Como é possível saber, com VBA, qual o nome do usuário que tem um ficheiro em excel aberto, ficheiro esse que está algures num servidor e não no disco local?

**Contexto**
Tenho procurado por uma função, em VBA, que me informe se um arquivo em excel esta aberto por um usuário e, em caso afirmativo, qual é o nome do usuário.

Consegui encontrar uma rotina que faz isso, porém apenas se o arquivo aberto estiver no disco local, o que não é o meu caso, segue a função citada:

```
Function Excel_File_in_use_by(FilePath As String) As String
    Dim strTempFile As String
    Dim iPos As Integer, iRetVal As Integer
    Dim objFSO As Object, objWMIService As Object, objFileSecuritySettings As Object, objSD As Object
    iPos = InStrRev(FilePath, "\")
    strTempFile = left(FilePath, iPos - 1) & "\~$" & Mid(FilePath, iPos + 1)
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If objFSO.FileExists(strTempFile) Then
        Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:")
        Set objFileSecuritySettings = objWMIService.Get("Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting='" & strTempFile & "'")
        iRetVal = objFileSecuritySettings.GetSecurityDescriptor(objSD)
        If iRetVal = 0 Then
            Excel_File_in_use_by = objSD.Owner.Name
        Else
            Excel_File_in_use_by = "unknown"
        End If
        Set objWMIService = Nothing
        Set objFileSecuritySettings = Nothing
        Set objSD = Nothing
    Else
        Excel_File_in_use_by = vbNullString
    End If
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    End Function
```

Eu precisava de uma função para verificar se um arquivo específico, neste caso um arquivo excel365, colocado em um servidor específico, está aberto por um usuário e, em caso afirmativo, qual é o nome do usuário.

É possível fazer isso no VBA?

Como implementar isso?

Comment: Legal as respostas, mas o pessoal deveria se atentar a pergunta feita.
A Pergunta feita, que inclusive é mesma duvida minha, é querer saber qual é o usuário da rede que está com a planilha aberta.
Todos os metodos respondidos são baseados no computador, mas dessa forma sempre vai retornar

Answer (score 0):

O nome de usuário do computador Windows pode ser visualizado da seguinte maneira:

```
Dim usuarioPC As String, usuario As String

usuario = Environ("username")
usuarioPC = Application.UserName

MsgBox "O usuário deste PC é o " & usuarioPC
MsgBox "O usuário é o " & usuario
```

Em que é utilizado o [Application.UserName](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/api/excel.application.username) ou o [Environ](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/environ-function)

Ou utilizar a seguinte função com a referência `wScript` para obter o nome do Computador em que o Excel foi aberto:

```
Public Function ComputerName() As String
'' Returns the host name

'' Uses late-binding: bad for performance and stability, useful for
'' code portability. The correct declaration is:
'' https://stackoverflow.com/a/10108951/7690982

'   Dim objNetwork  As IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshNetwork
'   Set objNetwork = New IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshNetwork

    Dim objNetwork As Object
    Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

    ComputerName = objNetwork.ComputerName

    Set objNetwork = Nothing

End Function
```

Para um teste visualize a saída da função numa MsgBox:

```
MsgBox ComputerName()
```

Ou outra função para obter o usuário do Computador:

```
Public Function UserName(Optional WithDomain As Boolean = False) As String
'' Returns the user's network name
'' https://stackoverflow.com/a/10108951/7690982

'' Uses late-binding: bad for performance and stability, useful for
'' code portability. The correct declaration is:

'   Dim objNetwork  As IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshNetwork
'   Set objNetwork = New IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshNetwork


    Dim objNetwork As Object
    Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

    If WithDomain Then
        UserName = objNetwork.UserDomain & "\" & objNetwork.UserName
    Else
        UserName = objNetwork.UserName
    End If

    Set objNetwork = Nothing

End Function
```

Ou a função [GetUserName](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/windows-api/retrieve-the-name-of-the-user-logged-on-to-the-network) da biblioteca "advapi32.dll":

```
' Access the GetUserNameA function in advapi32.dll and 
' call the function GetUserName. 
Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" _ 
 (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long 

' Main routine to retrieve user name. 
Function GetLogonName() As String 

 ' Dimension variables 
 Dim lpBuff As String * 255 
 Dim ret As Long 

 ' Get the user name minus any trailing spaces found in the name. 
 ret = GetUserName(lpBuff, 255) 

 If ret > 0 Then 
 GetLogonName = Left(lpBuff, InStr(lpBuff, Chr(0)) - 1) 
 Else 
 GetLogonName = vbNullString 
 End If 
End Function
```

Comment: O que se pretende não é o nome de usuário do computador Windows, mas o nome do usuário que tem um determinado ficheiro aberto num determinado servidor.

Comment: Seu pacote Office é o 2016? Não funciona muito bem no VBA desta versão e também depende da versão do Windows Server... Mas há muitos exemplos de realizar isso de formas não seguras, muitos abrem vulnerabilidades e dependem da forma que seu servidor está configurado e da versão...

Comment: Uso o Office365 com Windows10. Não consegui encontrar nenhum exemplo que indique qual o nome do usuário que tem o ficheiro aberto, só consigo arranjar exemplos que me indicam se o ficheiro está ou não aberto.